# @BeforeGroups and AfterGroups are throwing NullPointer in each run

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-eclipse

`@BeforeGroups` and `AfterGroups` are throwing `NullPointer Exception` for each run.

I am running BeforeGroups with Syntax: `@BeforeGroups(groups = "ICSInvoice")`
and testcases under it with Syntax:  `@Test(enabled = true, groups = "ICSInvoice")`

It is failing at the first line of method with the below error :

> Time elapsed: 333.578 sec  <<< FAILURE!
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Error coming at the first line:

```
public void initializeMyGroup() throws Exception { 
    logger.info("Enable Prerequisite for realms");
```

Logs:

> initializeMyGroup(com.buyer.tests.selenium2.UITests.ManageAc‌​countingTester)
>
> Time elapsed: 333.578 sec <<< FAILURE!
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
>   com.buyer.tests.selenium2.UITests.ManageAccountingTester.ini‌​tializeMyGroup(Manag‌​eAccountingTester.ja‌​va:160)

160 is the above line: 
`logger.info("Enable Prerequisite for realms");`

Comment: Could you share the stracktrace and the code from where the NPE comes?

Comment: Error coming at the first line:
public void initializeMyGroup() throws Exception {
  logger.info("Enable Prerequisite for xyz");

Comment: So `logger` is null.

Comment: Error coming at the first line:
public void initializeMyGroup() throws Exception {
  logger.info("Enable Prerequisite for realms");
  
Logs:
initializeMyGroup(com.buyer.tests.selenium2.UITests.ManageAccountingTester)  Time elapsed: 333.578 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.buyer.tests.selenium2.UITests.ManageAccountingTester.initializeMyGroup(ManageAccountingTester.java:160)

160 is the above line:   logger.info("Enable Prerequisite for realms");

Comment: but logger is working for other testcases, issue is coming only when it is in Before or After Group,

Is the syntax is correct for the annotation?

Comment: Please provide more details: how do you run the test? what are the options you use? what are the annotations on `initializeMyGroup`? where do you init the logger? ...